# I am just starting in code academy. I am getting the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript

My code is :

```
// Define quarter here.
var quarter = function(number);
{
    return number / 4;
}

if (quarter(12) % 3 === 0 ) {
  console.log("The statement is true");
} else {
  console.log("The statement is false");
}
```

It returns "SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Can someone point me to my error.  Thanks

Comment: `function(number);` <- semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var quarter = function(number);`

needs to be

`var quarter = function(number)`

The semicolon is the unexpected token.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spare semicolon in the first line of code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon here: `var quarter = function(number);`